# Size of Icons In OneNote notebook when document is inserted as link: is there a way to change that?

Tags: pdf, icons, microsoft-onenote

When I add in a OneNote page a document but as a link, I cannot change the size of the icon.

Insert->Document (paperclip): Insert as printout or as link
-> Then you get an incon with a pdf picture part of the title.
I just would like to make this icon bigger. My vision is not anymore what it was. Anyhow, I don't find how to do it.

Anyone knows how to?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Insert->Document (paperclip) 
Insert as printout or as link   ->
Then you get an incon with a pdf picture part of the title.
I just would like to make this icon bigger. My vision is not anymore what it was.   Anyhow, I don't find how to do it.